# Photoshop: How do I edit layer style Presets?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, layer-style

I just created a layer style preset in Photoshop and applied it to multiple shape layers. Now I would like to make several adjustments to the style. How do I do that? I want to automatically update all shape layers that are connected with this specific style.

Is that even possible?

Comment: This is a feature I've wished for years. Smart objects kinda get around the issue to some extent, but it's not as convenient as something like a `global style` option  would be.  Also scaling and rotating can be an issue with SO. Let alone the fact that you have to edit it in a separate document. Let's say you got a triangle and a circle and you want to have the same gradient and drop shadow in each. You can't use a smart object for that, since the shapes are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use smart object feature in photohsop, read more at:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html

or you can change one of theme's style and right click on there, "copy layer style" and select the the layers that you want to apply, then press "paste layer style".

Comment: [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Change the values and create a new layer preset. Choose all the shape layers and right click one of them and select "Clear layer style". While all of your layers selected, click your preset and you will be done. Photoshop can't update layer styles automatically.